# Selection and scrolling the element WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouseevent

There is a rectangle in my wpf application. There is also a **vertical** element inside the rectangle.

● This vertical element is selectable.

● At the same time, this element can slide left and right and show measurements while mouse moving.

I perform the elment selection with the using MouseDown event.

I perform left and right scrolling with the using MouseMove event.

But these two processes interfere with each other.

When I select the element with MouseDown, it starts to scroll left and right directly. What I want is to start scrolling 1 or 2 seconds after selecting the element.

I tried to  `Thread.Sleep(2000)` but it does not work correctly in mouse move.Because every movement it holds two second.

Below is a summary of my codes.

```
public void MouseLeftButtonDownEvent(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   FrameworkElement canvas = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
   var dataCxtx = canvas.DataContext;
   SelectElement(dataCtx,e);
                
 }

public void MouseMove(MouseEventArgs mouseArgs)
{
  if (_dragging && mouseArgs.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
     {
        //Wait for 2 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        if (_draggingPolyNode != null)
        {
           PolygonNode pTemporary = AccessElements.GetTemporaryPolygon(Nodes);
           if(DragTemporaryMullionElement(pTemporary,element, transform, mouseArgs))
              DL.CreateTemporaryHDimension(tempDimensionStartX, tempDimensionEndX, mousePosition.X, middleOfMullion, Nodes[0].Transform);
                    
         }
      }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Why the waiting? Wouldn't it be enough to start scrolling after the select operation has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay an operation for a specific amount of time by using a timer:

```cs
class MyControl
{
  private DispatcherTimer ScrollDelayTimer { get; } 

  public MyControl()
  {
    this.ScrollDelayTimer = new DispatcherTimer(
      TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 
      DispatcherPriority.Background, 
      OnScrollDelayTimerElapsed, 
      Application.Current.Dispatcher);
  }

  private void OnScrollDelayTimerElapsed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.ScrollDelayTimer.Stop();

    ScrollMarker();
  }

  private void ScrollMarker()
  {
    if (_draggingPolyNode != null)
    {
      PolygonNode pTemporary = AccessElements.GetTemporaryPolygon(Nodes);
      if (DragTemporaryMullionElement(pTemporary,element, transform, mouseArgs))
      {          
        DL.CreateTemporaryHDimension(tempDimensionStartX, tempDimensionEndX, mousePosition.X, middleOfMullion, Nodes[0].Transform);
      }                    
    }
  }

  private void MouseLeftButtonDownEvent(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     FrameworkElement canvas = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
     var dataCxtx = canvas.DataContext;
     SelectElement(dataCtx,e);                
  }

  private void MouseMove(MouseEventArgs mouseArgs)
  {
    if (_dragging && mouseArgs.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
      // Wait for 2 seconds
      this.ScrollDelayTimer.Start();        
    }
  }
}
```

Calling `Thread.Sleep` wil send the current thread to sleep. The current thread is the main thread - not good.
The timer will not freeze the main thread.

Comment: I tried but it says OnScrollDelayTimerElapsed is must be static. https://ibb.co/TY8bC5z

Comment: I had not written this code in a code editor. I just wrote it here on SO. But I should have been more careful. To fix it, simply move the initialization of the property to the constructor. I just left the constructor to keep the example compact.

Comment: I have updated the example to fix the issue. FYI, event handlers should be private or protected, but not public.

Comment: Mayn Thanx. It is worked.